# Security information github on a project via github API

Tags: security, github, github-pages, github-api

How do I get all Security Advisories using github api?

github -> Project ->  Security Advisories - View information about security vulnerabilities from this repository's maintainers.

Example Project:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/security/advisories

analogous to the List Repo commands

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/tensorflow/tensorflow/contributors
```

One more Example via github Explorer:

```
query
{
     securityAdvisories(first: 100) {
    totalCount
    pageInfo {
        endCursor
        startCursor
    }
    nodes {
        description
        summary
        cvss {
        vectorString
        }
        databaseId
        identifiers {
        type
        value
        }
        ghsaId
    }
    }
}
```

But i have no idea, how to get the security advisories for one project?

Thank you very much for any hints

Comment: I am also interested in this. I'd like to query https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/security/advisories via an API.

Comment: Yeah me too, want to know how many open advisories for a given project. Tried to clone the weird POST with multipart form to /security/counts but keep getting 406.